# Gradle dependency project test-jar

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle, gradle-dependencies

I have a multi-module gradle project and I want to make use of some of the test classes from the shared module in my dependent module.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':shared-module')

    testCompile project(':shared-module'), classifier: 'test-jar'
}
```

The first dependency works, but the testCompile dependency does not work. I cannot seem to find the syntax for it. The maven equivalent would be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>shared-module</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':shared-module')
    testCompile project(path: ':shared-module', configuration: 'testRuntime') 
}
```

Comment: Won't work with Gradle 4 [Java library](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) plugin (replaces Java plugin). `testImplementation` or `testRuntimeOnly` are not consumable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the nebula [test jar plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-publishing-plugin/blob/master/README.md#nebulatest-jar---deprecated)

***Note***
Nebula have deprecated this plugin as they believe test utilities should live in their own project. I tend to agree with them